# Add Links to descrition of Bqs Slider Pro - force links to be clickable preventDefaul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have implemented the great "feature" Slider Pro from this side:
https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro
Now i want to add "Links" to the description. This is easily possible by just adding the links in the html

[Link](http://www.google.de)

Unfortunately this link is not clickable. I think this is caused by the surrounding "area"  - a link on this area triggers the slide to load...
is there a way to force links to be clickable?

How can i tell the browser that the link with the class "sp-thumbnail-description" should be always clickable?

Comment: You need to provide working copy of your code ?

Comment: Hi! The main problem lies in the js file that i will share on the next post. I think all click events are switched off with preventdefault or are used to trigger the slideshow. I could post my html but this would not help much...

Comment: Having source code would help us to debug the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source file:
[Js File of SliderPro](http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js)
My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="example5" class="slider-pro">
    <div class="sp-slides">
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif"
                data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg"
                data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg"/>

        </div>      
    </div>

            <div class="sp-thumbnail">
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-image-container">
            </div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-text">
                <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">Sie benötigen ein<br />Schadengutachten?</div>
                <div class="sp-thumbnail-description"><a class="unbind" href="http://www.google.de">Hier finden Sie Informationen</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```